# JQuery Validation - letter by letter validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am working on a JQuery Mobile website with JQuery Validation to validate form fields. JQuery Validation sends an ajax call to server to validate user input using "remote".

There is a strange phenomenon that is, the first time the field is being validated, the ajax call does not get triggered until the whole word is typed. Well that is what I want. However, when it gets validated the first time and then when it receives subsequent focuses afterwards, the ajax call gets triggered every time a letter is typed.

Any idea about it? Is it a bug?

My code as follows:

```
$("#form1").validate({

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {
                "txt-username": {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "ManageAccessServlet?action=checkUsernameExist",
                        type: "get"
                    }
                },
                "txt-firstname": "required",
                "txt-lastname": "required",
                "txt-email": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                "txt-password": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                }
            },

            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {
                "txt-username": "Username cannot be empty or it has been occupied in the system",
                "txt-firstname": "Please enter your first name",
                "txt-lastname": "Please enter your last name",
                "txt-password": {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
                },
                "txt-email": "Please enter a valid email address"
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

HTML is as below:

```
<form action="SignupServlet" method="POST" id="form1">
            <div data-role="collapsible" id="collapPersonalDetails" data-collapsed="false">
                <h1>Personal Information</h1>
                <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <label for="txt-username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txt-username" id="txt-username" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <label for="txt-password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="txt-password" id="txt-password" value="">
                </div>
```

... ...

Comment: What are you using to trigger the Ajax request? Is it on keyup/keydown/submission of form/button?

Comment: If it was a bug, then Stack Overflow is not the place to report it.  Otherwise, we need to see a minimal example of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've shown us that would prevent all validation from occurring on keyup _after_ the initial click of the submit button.  What do you see in the console log after each keystroke?  It should be reporting every ajax attempt and the server response.

Comment: @Sparky - Yes, I can see every ajax attempt reported on the console log after each keystroke. These all happened well before I hit Submit.

Comment: I inspected one of my own forms using the remote validation method.  It is working as designed.  See my edited answer which contains a clarification.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Any idea about it? Is it a bug?"*

No, this is not a bug.  This is how the plugin is designed to operate.  It's called "lazy" validation.

You will not have any (`required`) validation on focus out or key-up until *after* the form submit button is clicked for the first time.  However, other validation rules will be triggered on subsequent data entry attempts *after* the first "focus out" event.

The opposite of "lazy" validation is called "eager".

---

**EDIT**:

Although entirely unclear in the OP, he simply wanted to disable the `onkeyup` validation option as evidenced by his own answer.

Comment: This happened even if before I hit the Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I had to add additional "onkeyup: false" as option to the "validate" function. This prevents validation ajax call from being triggered on each keystroke. Validation happens only when the whole word is entered and the input box loses focus.

Comment: Problem solved?  You never asked about solving anything or how to disable the `onkeyup` validation.  You asked if you had a bug.